# Comment model for User only Django

Tags: python, django

I hope you're well. I'm beginning with Django. I'd like to create a comment for users only.
I've created a UserProfile page before (with image for each member).

For my comment models. Do I need to add field for the image related to UserProfile? Or User is enough, like that? if a user comment something I want to display his username and his image.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="comments")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=160)
    publishing_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
     
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

models.py (UserProfile)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,default='user/user-128.png', upload_to='user/')
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    
    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 200 or img.width > 200:
            new_size = (200, 200)
            img.thumbnail(new_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
            
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add image field or user name field in comment model as User model is its foreign key.

You can use like this
Comments = Comment.objects.values('post' , 'user__name', 'user__image')

Comment: Thanks for your response @vikash :)